# Redis remove slave from replication along with sentinel

Tags: replication, redis

I have a 3-nodes Redis replication and a 3-nodes Sentinel. I want to remove one slave.

I tried stop slave and remove `slaveof 10.128.130.139 6379` from configuration. But it became slave again after I started it. And `slaveof` was back again in config.

After reading [SLAVEOF](http://redis.io/commands/SLAVEOF), I tried invoking `SLAVEOF NO ONE`. But it became slave again after 1 min.

I guess Sentinel reconfig it to slave. How can I remove one slave in my case where Sentinel exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I should read [sentinel doc](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) carefully. It's mentioned in sections *Adding or removing Sentinels* and *Removing the old master or unreachable slaves*.

These are steps:

- Shut down the redis slave to be removed.
- Remove `slaveof` statement from conf

  ```
  # Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
  slaveof 10.128.130.139 6379
  ```
- Send a `SENTINEL RESET mastername` command to all  Sentinel instances. One after the other, waiting at least 30 seconds between instances.

Now the redis slave is standalone, and sentinels forget this slave.